# When working on a responsive web, can I use % or vw units for font size?

Tags: css, responsive, font-size, percentage

Do I have to use the font size in em or rem units? Can't I use the %vw units?

The width of the speech bubble is % unit, so if the browser size decreases, the font size is fixed, it cannot match the speech bubble. So, I'm going to use vw unit of the font-size. Is this the recommended usage? Or should we avoid doing this if possible? Should I use em or rem units?

I used the % unit, so even if it's 100%, the letters are too small. If I use the vw unit, the font size comes out exactly, but if I use the vw unit, will there be a problem if the horizontal resolution is over 1920 and bigger? The max-width value of the body tag is 1920px on the site I make.

Comment: You can use vw units if you wish. Probably as well to be careful that you don't get too small a font-size that way. You could use clamp to make sure it stays readable/not too huge, but of course it may spill out of your bubble that way on e.g. a very narrow viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percent (%) as css font size: 100% is equal to the current font size. Think of it this way: 50% is 0.5 times larger ( half smaller ) and 150% is 150 percent of the font size.

```html
<p style="font-size:100%;">Font 100%</p>
<p style="font-size:50%;">Font 50%.</p>
<p style="font-size:150%;">Font 150%.</p>
```

For a responsive font you can use [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts) width/height,

```html
<h1 style="font-size:8vw;">Hello World</h1>
<p style="font-size:2vw;">Resize the browser window to see how the font size scales.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I heard that it is better to use em for font-size, but I would like to use a variable size rather than a fixed size.
Is it okay to make font-size % or vw in the process of creating a responsive web? I wonder if it's not recommended. Especially for vw, when max-width is 1920px, I am worried that the size of the letters will be doubled when viewed on a monitor such as 3840x2160 resolution. If so, should I use % units to use variable font-size?

Comment: CSS offers a number of different units for expressing length ( em, px, % ... ), the font size doesn't change on screen/window size changes. If you want a font responsive you can use: viewport, media-query, javascript and set size based the window size or CSS calc, min, max, This link can be useful: https://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-do-max-font-size-in-css/

Answer (score 0):

See [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts/#font-size-prop):

> Name:     `font-size`
>  Value:  `<absolute-size>` | `<relative-size>` |
> `<length-percentage [0,∞]>` | math
>
> - `<absolute-size>`
>
> An `<absolute-size>` keyword refers to an entry in a table of font
> sizes computed and kept by the user agent. Possible values are:
>
> ```
> [ xx-small | x-small | small | medium | large | x-large | xx-large ]
> ```
>
> - `<relative-size>`
>
> A `<relative-size>` keyword is interpreted relative to the table of
> font sizes and the computed ‘font-size’ of the parent element.
> Possible values are:
>
> ```
> [ larger | smaller ]
> ```
>
> For example, if the parent element has a font size of ‘medium’, a
> value of ‘larger’ will make the font size of the current element be
> ‘large’. If the parent element's size is not close to a table entry,
> the user agent is free to interpolate between table entries or round
> off to the closest one. The user agent may have to extrapolate table
> values if the numerical value goes beyond the keywords.
>
> - `<length-percentage>`
>
> A length value [CSS-VALUES] specifies an absolute font size
> (independent of the user agent's font table). Negative lengths are
> invalid.
>
> A percentage value specifies an absolute font size relative to the
> parent element's font size. Use of percentage values, or values in
> ems, leads to more robust and cascadable style sheets. Negative
> percentages are invalid.

Units relative to the viewport size are not supported.